# Calling .net web service on IIS server from Android using ksoap2

Tags: android, .net, ksoap2

I'm a newbie at `Android`, `KSOAP`.  I do mostly `.NET`.  I'm writing an `Android App` that's trying to pull data from a `.NET Service` on an `IIS Server`.

The line causeing the error is:

```
androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
```

It fails with the exception:

> org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: expected: START_TAG
>   {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Envelope
>   (position:START_TAG @2:7 in java.io.InputStreamReader@41527620)

The `Web Service` I'm calling seems to return `XML` just fine when invoking from a browser.

Do I need to do something on the `IIS Server` for the service to be called successfully from `KSOAP2`?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Andriod code:

```
package com.example.vdu;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import org.ksoap2.*;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.*;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class DirectorySyncActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://www.mycompany.com/";
    private static final String URL = "http://www.mycompany.com/vdus/service1.asmx/Directory";
    private static final String METHOD_NAME = "Directory";
    private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://www.mycompany.com/vdus/Directory";
    Object response;
    TextView tv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getdirdata();
    }

        private void getdirdata() {

            new Thread() {
            @Override
                public void run() {
                try
                    {
                    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
                    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope =new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
                    envelope.dotNet = true;
                    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
                    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
                    androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
                    java.lang.String directorystring = (String)envelope.getResponse().toString();
                    }           
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }.start();
            }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.directory_sync, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private static final String URL = "http://www.mycompany.com/vdus/service1.asmx";
```

instead of this:

```
private static final String URL = "http://www.mycompany.com/vdus/service1.asmx/Directory";
```